# What is the correct way to share gsuite add-on with external users without publishing to Marketplace?

Tags: gsuite-addons

Using a company domain gsuite account, I have successfully deployed a gsuite Google Docs add-on for my company domain using the G Suite Marketplace SDK, but I have some users that are outside of the domain e.g. part-timers, contractors etc. who are using their personal name@gmail.com accounts. How can I share the add-on with them to install?

In G Suite Marketplace SDK > Publish, I have this App URL, but it gives error 400 so I don't know where to go next.

```
https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/appname/<project number>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will need to publish it to the Public for anyone outside your domain to install it.

Here is some more info:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gsuite-addons#step_4_configure_the_marketplace_sdk